# How do I prevent Google Docs from changing (some) spaces to tabs when pasting from text editor?

Tags: google-docs

What's worse is that in some cases it behaves as if it gets rid of the 4 spaces instead of replacing with a tab. This does horrible things to any ASCII diagrams appearing in code.

Ex: take the following and paste it into a text editor like notepad++ then copy/paste into google docs (it will be formatted correctly if you paste it directly in):

```
else if(xp>=Width){
    if(yp<0){
        xb=Width;
        yb=0;
    }
    else if(y>Height){
        xb=Width;
        yb=Height;
    }
}
```

will end up looking like:

```
else if(xp>=Width){
    if(yp<0){
    xb=Width;
    yb=0;
    }
    else if(y>Height){
    xb=Width;
    yb=Height;
    }
}
```

and if you move the cursor around, it behaves like there is a tab in front of each inner if/else and 5 spaces in front of xb=Width, etc.

Edit: in the current version of google docs, using the "paste without formatting" and "remove formatting from selected text" options together are effective for getting code INTO google docs, though it still replaces tabs with spaces when you past FROM google docs.

Comment: Not sure, but could this work? https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/58153/21583

Comment: I pasted it into Atom then Google Docs, and using both Ctrl-V and Ctrl-Shift-V, I was able to have it come out perfectly in Google. Could be an issue with the particular text editor, browser, or combination of the two?

Comment: I've tried this from multiple text editors in both windows 10 and Ubuntu, with Firefox, Chrome, Chromium, and even Internet Explorer. Not only does it sometimes replace tabs with spaces and/or spaces with tabs, but it doesn't seem to do either of these with any sort of pattern I've been able to discern so I can't even write a script to do the translation.  Could you let me know which OS & browser you were using?

Comment: I am using VSCode (version 1.43).  When I use Copy and Paste from VS Code to Google docs it preserves tabs or spaces.  However, it includes the VSCode theme (black background etc).  If I then use Google docs "clear formatting" the layout is changed. The same thing happens if I try Paste without formatting in Shift+Ctrl+V. I'm using Windows 10.

Answer (score 11):

Neither <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> nor <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> worked for me - both pasted spaces as tabs.  However, I tried **find and replace**, checked **with regular expressions**, and changed `\t` into four spaces.  My example then lined up correctly.

Comment: Too bad Google slides do not have find/replace with regex (but do convert some spaces to tabs)

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

Open a plain text editor that supports dragging selected text to another application.

First paste the text into that editor, select it, and drag into the desired location in the Google doc.